# Can we specify a pattern for topics in kafka hdfs connect .

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

KafkaConsumer supports both a list of topics or a pattern when subscribing.
Can we do the same thing with hdfs connect?

I cannot find any configuration related to that in the [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/hdfs_connector.html).

Comment: `topics.regex` was added in Confluent 4.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Looks like topic patterns is a feature which was pulled in Nov 2017, you can see the original ticket [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3073) and the wiki [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-215%3A+Add+topic+regex+support+for+Connect+sinks). From what I can tell you have to use the `topics.regex` property instead of `topics`.